# How replace text of an element which is loaded with ajax?

Tags: jquery, str-replace

I need to replace (with jquery) the text for an element which is not loaded on document.ready. The element is loaded with ajax.

I tried with:

```
    $('#my-div label').live({
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace('text', 'my text')); 

    });
```

the html is something like

```
<div id="my-div"><label>text</label></div>
```

Comment: You have to do it on your `success` ajax handler. Please paste it on your question

Comment: Since it's loaded via AJAX, in your AJAX callback function, you have the element. Can't you change the element in that moment?

Comment: I can't modify the AJAX function. Is a drupal module, I will lost my changes every time I update the module...

Comment: user `$(document).ajaxComplete`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var $label = $("#my-div label");
    var text = $label.text();
    $label.text(text.replace("text", "my text")); 
});
```

That will fire that function every time an ajax call is completed.  That's ANY ajax call on that page.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use live. You aren't binding any event here. In the success function of your ajax, just put

```
    var label = $('#my-div label');
    label.text(label.text().replace('text', 'my text'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#my-div label').text('my text');
});
```

try to use **[ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)** or **[ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/)**

Comment: works even without ajaxComplete, ajaxSuccess, etc.